# Google Map Custom Marker Image Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this page where I have one custom marker rendering, and another not rendering.  Would anyone know why?  The http://www.comehike.com/img/smile.gif does not show up and the car image does show up.

The page url with the map (towards the bottom) is here:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/hike_carpool.php?hike_id=125

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was something stupid I was doing. Never mind :)

Comment: @Grenadinik, you should probably delete your question since it's not really a universal problem.